# free-ing memory allocated by another binary

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I have a small test app (let's call it `test.c`) and a small shared library code (let's call it `plugin.c`).

The test app is compiled with `$(CC) -o $@ $^ -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -ldl -lcrypto -Wl,--export-dynamic`, while the shared library code is compiled with `$(CC) -c $< -o $@ -pedantic -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -fpic -I.`.

The test code `dlopen`s the shared library and then it calls `void plugin_test(<ptr_to_function> f)` function. The function `plugin_test` receives a pointer to a funcion (called `f`) that will `malloc` a few bytes and return then as `unsigned char *`.

So, generally speaking, it looks that way:

1. Run `test`
2. `test` loads `plugin`.
3. `test` runs `plugin_test` function.
4. `plugin_test` function runs `f` which is inside `test`
5. `f` mallocs a few bytes and returns them.
6. `plugin_test` saves what `f` returned in a `unsigned char *`

My question is: is it `free(returned_pointer_from_f_function)` supposed to work if I call it from inside `plugin_test`?

I'm getting a crash (segfault) because of that instruction. 
I have noticed (from gdb bt full) that there seems to be some kind of pointer mismatch.

This is the backtrace:

```
*** Error in `./test': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000d10066 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x72e5f)[0x7f2637464e5f]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7862e)[0x7f263746a62e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x79307)[0x7f263746b307]
./plugins/tt.so(match+0x275)[0x7f2636fdac6d]
./test(main+0x515)[0x401b2c]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f2637413bc5]
./test[0x4012c9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 24641553                           /home/alexandernst/Proyectos/mem_dumper/test
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:11 24641553                           /home/alexandernst/Proyectos/mem_dumper/test
00d10000-01539000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f2636dc4000-7f2636dd9000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1489785                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2636dd9000-7f2636fd9000 ---p 00015000 08:02 1489785                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2636fd9000-7f2636fda000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 1489785                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2636fda000-7f2636fdb000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 24641572                   /home/alexandernst/Proyectos/mem_dumper/plugins/tt.so
7f2636fdb000-7f26371db000 ---p 00001000 08:11 24641572                   /home/alexandernst/Proyectos/mem_dumper/plugins/tt.so
7f26371db000-7f26371dc000 rw-p 00001000 08:11 24641572                   /home/alexandernst/Proyectos/mem_dumper/plugins/tt.so
7f26371dc000-7f26371f1000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1448187                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
7f26371f1000-7f26373f0000 ---p 00015000 08:02 1448187                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
7f26373f0000-7f26373f1000 r--p 00014000 08:02 1448187                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
7f26373f1000-7f26373f2000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 1448187                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
7f26373f2000-7f2637594000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1445202                    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
7f2637594000-7f2637793000 ---p 001a2000 08:02 1445202                    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
7f2637793000-7f2637797000 r--p 001a1000 08:02 1445202                    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
7f2637797000-7f2637799000 rw-p 001a5000 08:02 1445202                    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
7f2637799000-7f263779d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f263779d000-7f263797c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1453900                    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f263797c000-7f2637b7b000 ---p 001df000 08:02 1453900                    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f2637b7b000-7f2637b96000 r--p 001de000 08:02 1453900                    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f2637b96000-7f2637ba1000 rw-p 001f9000 08:02 1453900                    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f2637ba1000-7f2637ba5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2637ba5000-7f2637ba8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1445237                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
7f2637ba8000-7f2637da7000 ---p 00003000 08:02 1445237                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
7f2637da7000-7f2637da8000 r--p 00002000 08:02 1445237                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
7f2637da8000-7f2637da9000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 1445237                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
7f2637da9000-7f2637dc9000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1445178                    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
7f2637f8a000-7f2637f8f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2637fc5000-7f2637fc8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2637fc8000-7f2637fc9000 r--p 0001f000 08:02 1445178                    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
7f2637fc9000-7f2637fca000 rw-p 00020000 08:02 1445178                    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
7f2637fca000-7f2637fcb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffd30f9000-7fffd311a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffd31fe000-7fffd3200000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
[alexandernst@stupidbox mem_dumper]# gdb ./test core.30740 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/alexandernst/Proyectos/mem_dumper/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 30740]

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fffd31fe000
Core was generated by `./test 29882'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f26374273d9 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007f26374273d9 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007f26374287d8 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007f2637464e64 in __libc_message () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007f263746a62e in malloc_printerr () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007f263746b307 in _int_free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007f2636fdac6d in match (mem_buf=0xd186f0 "@\020\206\377M\177", mem_size=1048576) at plugins/tt.c:82
        hash = 0xd10280 "/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1"
        str_hash = 0xd10066 ""
        fname = "./dumps/94a92daf9555939d14300d68e1f69392-1384545306-936816-4"
        i = 936816
        size = 0xd10280 "/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1"
        fcontent = 0xd102a0 "P", <incomplete sequence \321>
        fsize = 48
#6  0x0000000000401b2c in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Note the direction at line 1 and the direction at line 81.

EDIT: This is my code:

Inside `test`

```
unsigned char *hash_to_str(unsigned char *mem_hash){
    int i;
    unsigned char *hash;

    hash = malloc(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2);

    for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        sprintf(&hash[i*2], "%02x", mem_hash[i]);
    return hash;
}
```

Insite `plugin`

```
unsigned char *str_hash = _->hash_to_str(hash);
printf("%s\n", str_hash);
free(str_hash);
```

EDIT:

bt full after fixing the `+1` byte for snprintf as suggested:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007fe04b266024 in free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007fe04add2c6d in match (mem_buf=0x7fe04a2f1010 "", mem_size=11403264) at plugins/tt.c:82
        hash = 0x25ca280 ""
        str_hash = 0x6677732e31 <Address 0x6677732e31 out of bounds>
        fname = "./dumps/ee0c6f3d65d31c4af6db76a47e28aff2-1384569665-9257680-"
        i = 9257680
        size = 0x25ca280 ""
        fcontent = 0x25d26f0 "FWS", <incomplete sequence \353\234>
        fsize = 40171
#2  0x0000000000401b2c in main ()
```

EDIT: I don't know if this has something to do, but I'm running `test` with `sudo` as I need to `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH...)`.

Comment: The ptr passed to free from inside match() at tt.c line 82 was probably not from malloc. It shouldn't matter whether it was malloc'ed inside the "plugin" or not.

Comment: The value of that pointer `0x0000000000d10066` suggests (at least to me) it is an automatic variable address (or not an address at all). Either that or you have the oddest dynamic memory manager I've ever seen, since it is clearly not an aligned value (only the bottom bit is clear)

Comment: Can you check my edit, please?

Comment: Have you run valgrind on this?

Comment: @CharlieBurns No, not yet. What should I'd be looking for? mem leaks?

Comment: @alexandernst that was about to be my next suggestion as well. Valgrind is extraordinary about finding issues like this. Frankly, I'd have it enabled to check *everything*. Also, I may be missing something, but is the *output* of that `printf()` anywhere in all this? (and just for fun, change it to `printf("%p : %s\n", str_hash, str_hash);`)

Comment: Valgrind will tell about reading and writing memory locations in the heap that have not malloced. For example, writing past the end of a malloc'ed block.

Comment: Yup, something is really wrong. valgrind is yelling at me. I should fix all those (at least 4 different) errors and then come back. Thank you for the help anyways! :)

Comment: Print pointer value after malloc and before free and see if they match.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: is it free(returned_pointer_from_f_function) supposed
>   to work if I call it from inside plugin_test?

Yes.You are somehow free()'ing a pointer that was not returned from malloc.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
hash = malloc(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2);
```

You're not allocating space for your terminating character, so the last `sprintf()` will step off the end of your allocation, write to memory not owned by you, and officially welcome you with open arms into the land of **undefined behavior**. In the process you're likely stomping your free-list or other heap management structures.

Change it to this:

```
hash = malloc(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2 + 1);
```

And try it again.

Comment: Ouch, indeed, there is a bug. But after fixing that line I'm getting the same segfault.

Comment: @alexandernst with the same value ? and stack dump? And you're *sure* up updated the .so that had the bug above?

Comment: Let me clean and re-run everything, if result changes I'll update my questions

Comment: Ok, so now it's crystal clear that the address of ```str_hash``` is out of bounds. But why?

Comment: Eh. at least its progress. In case you didn't do the math, 0x6677732e31 is `fws.1`, or `1.swf` in little endian form. I don't suppose that means anything to you? Just crunching stuff in my head, so its entirely possible its totally unrelated. I just noticed your `fcontent` had `"FWS"` as its value, so I'm thinking this could be related somehow.